# EJB injection impossible in a war application deployed on wildfly via cargo maven plugin

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, java-ee-7, wildfly-10, cargo-maven2-plugin

I deploy a war application using cargo maven plugin (wildfly 10 app server) and this happens successfully! But i can't injecting an ejb in a class.
This is the console when i exec cargo:run(see the null instance in tail of log..)

```
[INFO] --- cargo-maven2-plugin:1.5.0:run (default-cli) @ dwrexmio ---
[INFO] [en2.ContainerRunMojo] Resolved container artifact org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-container-wildfly:jar:1.5.0 for container wildfly10x
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Parsed JBoss version = [10.x]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] WildFly 10.x starting...
[INFO] [neLocalConfiguration] Configuring JBoss using the [standalone] server configuration
[INFO] [stalledLocalDeployer] Deploying [C:\Progetti\altri\Dwr-ex-mio\dwrexmio\target\dwrexmio.war] to [C:\Progetti\altri\Dwr-ex-mio\dwrexmio\target\cargo\configurations\wildfly10x/deployments]...
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9000
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:06,010 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.2.Final
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:06,511 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:06,596 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) starting
...
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:09,462 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:09,468 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:09,555 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\Progetti\altri\Dwr-ex-mio\dwrexmio\target\cargo\installs\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\wildfly-10.1.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:09,773 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:09,774 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:10,099 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\Progetti\altri\Dwr-ex-mio\dwrexmio\target\cargo\configurations\wildfly10x\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:10,126 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Progetti\altri\Dwr-ex-mio\dwrexmio\target\cargo\configurations\wildfly10x\deployments
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:10,134 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "cargocpc.war" (runtime-name: "cargocpc.war")
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:10,150 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "dwrexmio.war" (runtime-name: "dwrexmio.war")
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:10,642 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-8) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.4.Final
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:10,758 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:10,760 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:10,764 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:10,765 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:10,765 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:10,773 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:10,781 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:9090
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:10,883 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:8443
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:11,183 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:11,246 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.5.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.6) 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:12,275 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment dwrexmio.war
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:12,324 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /cargocpc
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:12,384 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-6) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] WildFly 10.x started on port [9090]
[INFO] Press Ctrl-C to stop the container...
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:12,484 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'TimerEjb2' in deployment unit 'deployment "dwrexmio.war"' are as follows:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:global/dwrexmio/TimerEjb2!com.cadit.bean.TimerEjb2
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:app/dwrexmio/TimerEjb2!com.cadit.bean.TimerEjb2
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:module/TimerEjb2!com.cadit.bean.TimerEjb2
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:global/dwrexmio/TimerEjb2
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:app/dwrexmio/TimerEjb2
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:module/TimerEjb2
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:12,675 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:12,680 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:12,791 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-000900: 2.3.5 (Final)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:13,205 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:13,978 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.13.SP1 20160303-1204 for context '/dwrexmio'
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:14,751 INFO  [org.directwebremoting.log.startup] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Starting: DwrServlet v3.0.3-dev on WildFly 2.2.0.Final - 1.4.0.Final / JDK 1.8.0_65 from Oracle Corporation at /dwrexmio
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:14,797 INFO  [org.directwebremoting.log.startup] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Starting: Using container abstraction org.directwebremoting.server.servlet2.Servlet24ContainerAbstraction
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:14,913 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /dwrexmio
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:14,951 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "dwrexmio.war" (runtime-name : "dwrexmio.war")
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:14,951 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "cargocpc.war" (runtime-name : "cargocpc.war")
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:15,111 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9050/management
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:15,111 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9050
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:32:15,112 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started in 9478ms - Started 536 of 778 services (415 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 11:33:02,043 INFO  [stdout] (default task-45) null
```

My ejb is Timer2EJB:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedScheduledExecutorService;


    @Stateless
    public class TimerEjb2 {


        @Resource//(lookup="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default")
        private ManagedScheduledExecutorService executorService; 


        public TimerEjb2() {

        }

        public void startTask(PushEndPoint pushEndpoint){
            executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(pushEndpoint, 1, 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }

        public void shutdownTask(){
            executorService.shutdown();
            try {
                executorService.awaitTermination(3000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

pushEndpoint implements Runnable.
But when i execute this class the injection not happens:

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;

public class Testejb {

    @EJB
       TimerEjb2 timerEjb2;

    public void test(){
        System.out.println(timerEjb2); <--this is null in log!
    }
}
```

the same things if i add (lookup="java:global/dwrexmio/TimerEjb2!com.cadit.bean.TimerEjb2") before @EJB

In webapp\WEB-INF there is web.xml and the beans.xml and ejb-jar.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         version="3.1"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">

</ejb-jar>
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.cadit</groupId>
  <artifactId>dwrexmio</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>dwrexmio Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <finalName>dwrexmio</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <containerId>wildfly10x</containerId>
                        <zipUrlInstaller>
                                <url>
                                    http://download.jboss.org/wildfly/10.1.0.Final/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.zip
                                </url>
                        </zipUrlInstaller>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <copy>
                                <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/jboss/configuration/</file>
                                <todir>
                                    ../../installs/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration
                                </todir>
                                <configfile>true</configfile>
                                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            </copy>
                            <copy>
                                <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/jboss/configuration/</file>
                                <todir>../../configurations/wildfly10x/configuration</todir>
                                <configfile>true</configfile>
                                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            </copy>
                        </files>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.start.jvmargs>
                                -Xdebug
                                -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9000
                                -Xnoagent
                                -Djava.compiler=NONE
                            </cargo.start.jvmargs>
                            <cargo.jboss.modules.dir>modules</cargo.jboss.modules.dir>
                            <cargo.servlet.port>9090</cargo.servlet.port>
                            <cargo.jboss.management-http.port>9050</cargo.jboss.management-http.port>
                            <cargo.servlet.users>admin:admin</cargo.servlet.users>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
            <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



  </dependencies>

</project>
```

what's wrong?

Thank you very much!

Roby

Answer (score 0):

You're `Testejb` is not managed by the container and therefore the EJB cannot be injected. You need to run your test with something like [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) that can run tests in the container.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Stateless` to your `Testejb` otherwise it is not managed by the application server and dependencies are not injected.